# Java Stream grouping and counting occuerences

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects representing trades in a market. Each trade has an opening and closing time and a profit. I want to group them by a month and then count a number of trades with profit > 0 and < 0 in each month = create a Map with following structure {"MM" = {"Win" = numberOfWinTrades, "Loss" = numberOfLossTrades}, "MM" ...}

I came up with the following code, but I am not able to implement the condition into it:

```
filteredOrders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getCreationTime().substring(5,7),
                Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getPlUsd() > 0, Collectors.counting())));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inline mapping based on the `order.getPlUsd() > 0`/`order.getPlUsd() < 0` condition:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> monthPlusdGroups = 
    filteredOrders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getCreationTime().substring(5, 7),
             Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getPlusd() > 0 ? "Win" : "Loss", 
                                   Collectors.counting())));
```

Just note that this implementation (`order.getPlusd() > 0 ? "Win" : "Loss"`) classifies $0 profits as "Loss".

Comment: how about `partitioningBy`?

Comment: @Naman I suppose one can use it as well, but I thought the classification wouldn't be binary and that the condition would have to be more elaborate than this

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've just added a filtr to get rid of the 0$: `filteredOrders.stream()
    .filter(order -> order.getPlUsd() != 0)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getCreationTime().substring(5, 7),
      Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getPlUsd() > 0 ? "Win" : "Loss",
        Collectors.counting())));`